# Converting Audio to AC-3 using afconvert?

Tags: audio, command-line, file-conversion

I'm trying to use `afconvert` to convert an audio file to AC-3 format. It's 5.1 audio, having already been converted from DTS to WAV (using `ffmpeg`, since `afconvert` doesn't seem to deal with DTS).

As you can see, I've tried various parameter incantations, including trying to use a different container formats, but with no success:

```
$ afconvert -f ac-3 test.wav 
Error: ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL failed ('typ?')
$ afconvert -f ac-3 -d ac-3 test.wav 
Error: ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL failed ('typ?')
$ afconvert -f caff -d AC-3 test.wav 
Error: ExtAudioFileSetProperty ('cfmt') failed ('fmt?')
```

I have been able to encode it to an AAC file successfully, so it's presumably something with the AC-3 encoding, but Googling those errors yields no results. Does anyone know how to properly convert to AC-3 with `afconvert`?

If you want to do some testing yourself, I found some free 5.1 DTS sample files [here](http://www.diatonis.com/surround_sound_music.html). Note that while the file extension is `.wav`, they're actually DTS files, not WAV. To replicate my desired workflow, decode to a WAV file with ffmpeg: `ffmpeg -i input.wav -acodec pcm_s16le -f wav output.wav`, then you'll have a proper 5.1 WAV file `afconvert` should be able to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use ffmpeg? This seemed to work for the [DTS WAV files here](http://www.diatonis.com/surround_sound_music.html):

```
ffmpeg -i test.wav -ab 640k test.ac3
```

Comment: Yeah, that's my fallback. In the past the ffmpeg AC3 encoders haven't had a great reputation for quality, which is why I was hoping to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Deleted original answer as it did not pertain.

Did an alternate test on my box, mainly to generate a file that would allow me to test afconvert, but came up with another solution to generate an AC3 file, which does not use ffmpeg:

So, starting with a mono 44100 wav file, I used 'sox' to merge multiple wav files into a multiple channel wav: surround.wav which I then used 'aften' to convert to an AC3 encoded file:

```
$ file surround.wav 
surround.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, 5 channels 44100 Hz

$ aften -b 448 -cmix 0 -smix 0 -dsur 2 -acmod 7 surround.wav surround.ac3


$ file surround.ac3 
surround.ac3: ATSC A/52 aka AC-3 aka Dolby Digital stream, 44.1 kHz,, complete main (CM) 3 front/2 rear, LFE on,, 448 kbit/s not Dolby Surround encoded
```

(src: http://parumi.wordpress.com/2007/12/12/how-to-create-multichannel-51-ac3-audio-and-video-in-linux/ )

Still working on why afconvert won't honor or work with the ac-3 format.

Comment: Thanks, but not really helpful. That's for converting to AAC, which as I noted in the question already works, but is not my desired output. It seems to be an issue specific to the AC3 conversion. I'll try to find a decent sample file and link to it later if you want to test some things out.

Comment: Sure thing. Like Lauri, I've been doing my audio conversion via ffmpeg and the like. :)  I'll update my answer if I get the file to encode.

Comment: Thanks. I've used `aften` before on my Linux box, but for some reason I didn't think it was available for OS X. Just discovered there's a Homebrew formula, so that's a good option. Still hoping out for an `afconvert` solution, but this was helpful, thanks!

Comment: No prob. Homebrew has been a great way to access many tools on Mac OS X. Answering your question pointed me to aften, so it's win-win. :)

Comment: Did some more digging and ran into an interesting problem:  "afinfo output.ac3"  this resulted in the error: "Fail: AudioFileOpenURL failed"  I suspect that the AC-3 codec as accessed via the af* binaries might be a bit wonky. The afinfo worked fine on the 5.1 channel wave file, however.

Comment: Aften is also easy to compile with CMake and should do what you're looking to accomplish. I downloaded the samples you mentioned, converted them to .wav, then used Aften to output to AC-3 format with no issues at all.